# How to configure docker engine inside eclipse-che environment

Tags: docker, kubectl, docker-desktop, eclipse-che

I have a mac and I have installed eclipse che using chectl inside docker-desktop using command

```
chectl server:deploy --platform=docker-desktop --installer=helm
```

In order to install any plugins/apks we have to have our own recepie so
I built a custom recipe using a docker file and have used image
FROM docker:dind
pushed it to docker hub  and my devfile looks like this where amoldeshpande/custom-node-test is my docker file pushed to dockerhub

```
apiVersion: 1.0.0
metadata:
  name: test
components:
  - mountSources: true
    endpoints:
      - name: test
        port: 3000
    memoryLimit: 512Mi
    type: dockerimage
    alias: nodejs
    image: amoldeshpande/custom-node-test
```

Now when I run docker command inside eclipse che workspace
/ $ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
I get this error.

I found out that it needs privileged access so I edited the che deployment file

```
kubectl edit deployment che  -n eclipse-che
```

and

```
securityContext:
     privileged: true



kubectl rollout restart deployment/che -n eclipse-che
```

And still, I get the same error.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use a docker inside the eclipse che env is to use buildah plugin which requires no additional setup as it does not requires any root access.
In the devfile, just add this plugin

```
 - id: moby/buildkit/latest
   type: chePlugin
```

And you can run all the docker commands.